# heroku migration issue

Tags: heroku, migration

After i run  heroku run db:migrate , i  got this error .   . the app works fine in development.i also did some research on this website , and try several solutions , seems not working.can somebody help me figure out how i can fix that ?

```
==  CreatePins: migrating =====================================================
-- create_table(:pins)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "pins_id_seq1" for serial column "pins.id"
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "pins" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "pins" ("id" serial primary key, "description" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp N
OT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL) /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_re
cord/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `exec'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is telling you that `pins` already exists. It could be that you have two migrations that create `pins` or the somehow you've managed to create a table without Rails knowing/remembering that it's run the migration. I've found you can get into this state if you use `heroku db:push` to push a single table, in this case `pins` to Heroku but not the contents of `schema_migrations` so when you try and run the migration the table is present.

If it's new and you don't have any data in pins you can use psql, pgadmin tools etc to drop the pins table, re-run the migration and have Rails execute the migration and store the fact it has done it (it stores the ident of the migration in schema_migrations table)